# Get an archive of all downloadable products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, download, product

I have a Woocommerce store with both physical and downloadable products, all created as simple products.

I can't seem to find a way to display an archive that displays all my downloadable products on one page. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Johannes

Answer (score 1):

> **Updated** - There are many ways.

**1) Woocommerce Shortcode:**

It is the **best** and **easiest** way and you can use it in any page of your choice. The following code will allow you to filter **downloadable products** in Woocommerce shortcodes:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'custom_shortcode_products_query', 10, 3 );
function custom_shortcode_products_query( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ) {
    if( ! is_admin() && 'downloadable' === $atts['class'] )
        $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'     => '_downloadable',
            'value'   => 'yes',
            'compare' => '=',
        );

    return $query_args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE:**

```
[products class='downloadable']
```

Or in php code

```
echo do_shortcode("[products class='downloadable']");
```

**Reference:** [Woocommerce Shortcodes documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6)

---

**2) The query string alternative:**

The following code will allow you to display in shop page the downloadable products for a specific query string like: `www.yoursite.com/shop/?downloadable=1`

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'downloadable_products', 30, 2 );
function downloadable_products( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // Only on archive pages
    if( is_admin() || ! is_shop() )
        return $meta_query; // exit

    if( isset($_GET['downloadable']) || $_GET['downloadable'] == '1' ){
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => '_downloadable',
            'value'   => 'yes',
            'compare' => '=',
        );
    }
    return $meta_query;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

Reference: [Exclude downloadable products from shop pages in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416223/exclude-downloadable-products-from-shop-pages-in-woocommerce/49416614#49416614)

Answer (score 0):

[You didn't look very far...](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query#parameters)

Above is a very simple way to display products which are downloadable.

Edit: Downvoted because I didn't spoon feed?

```
$products = wc_get_products( array(
    'downloadable' => true

) );
```

OR

```
$products = new WC_Product_Query( array(
    'downloadable' => false
) );

$products = $query->get_products();
```

Comment: Well it's down to a case of laziness vs productiveness - if you state you "can't find a way", it would imply that you've attempted and looked - yet the first Google link I came across was the above.

Comment: Maybe not - but it was a proactive attempt to help him do research.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get your hands dirty with code, try adding a category of "downloadable" to the products and then use the shortcode `[products category="downloadable"]` on a page.